# Is checklist or tick box (or something else) more common in British English?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

When referring to a list of items that you check off as you complete, would the British say, "checklist," "tick box," or something else?

Comment: related (but not exactly a duplicate): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152421/what-is-the-v-shaped-thing-called-one-puts-in-a-checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly it would be called a *Ticklist*. It can also be sent as *Tick list*.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a "checklist" (a list of things that you must think about, or that you must remember to do). 
British English: to tick, is to put a mark [✓] by an answer to show that it is correct. 
You can tick the box too!